# Chat client supporting Facebook?

Tags: pidgin, facebook

It seems that facebook more or less recently stopped to provide its XMPP Chat API. As a consequence, Ubuntu users can't chat anymore with facebook contacts using Pidgin for example. I am looking for a chat client able to connect with Facebook and Gmail contacts. I am not sure this is possible, but if any solution exists, I would be happy to try it.

Comment: Possible duplicate [How to grant application access for Facebook account](/q/714573)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible with pidgin and the purple-facebook. purple-facebook is a plugin and available in the official repository. To add the repository and install the plugin, use the following commands:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -rs)/ /' >> /etc/apt/sources.list.d/jgeboski.list"
cd /tmp && wget  http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/xUbuntu_$(lsb_release -rs)/Release.key
sudo apt-key add - < Release.key  
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install purple-facebook
```

After istalling open pidgin and add the account: Accounts -> Manage Accounts -> Add and choose "Facebook" and not "Facebook (XMPP)"

Source of purple-facebook: https://github.com/jgeboski/purple-facebook

Comment: Actually there is an official repository, which has and receives more recent updates. http://www.webupd8.org/2015/08/use-facebook-chat-in-pidgin-with-purple.html

Comment: @paul-götzinger according to [jgeboski's Software Packages](https://jgeboski.github.io/#package-repositories), the first CMD (it's missing a ".") should read: `deb http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/home:/jgeboski/<version> ./`

Answer (score 0):

The Thunderbird email client has a chat function for facebook.

```
1.Go to the "file" menu on top of the page. 
2.Select "chat account"
```

You should see this screenshot:

[image: chat1]

3.select facebook

4.click next

5.It will ask you for your username. Note: Here you need to add  your empathy username on facebook. 
To find this username go to the drop-down menu in the top right hand corner and click on "settings" I apologize, I cannot make a screenshot since it is in the title bar. From here you will see your username. Type everything marked in bold print plus the numbers.

6.Now it will ask you if you want an alias or not. You can simply select "next" here, if you wish.

7.Next Thunderbird will ask you for your password. Put this in.

8.Now select "finish" Facebook will connect your account. For a further resource, I found this tutorial to try and help you. I have this on my thunderbird account but I wanted a refresher. I found most of the information here and tested it:https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/instant-messaging-and-chat#w_configuring-chat. I hope this helps.

Comment: The XMPP chat API no longer works.